# How to find rows where 3 columns have the same number of characters?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

A table contains name, city and country.

Now need a SQL query for showing the name, city and country where the name, city and country have the same number of characters

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I am stuck here: SELECT name, LENGTH(name), city, LENGTH(city), capital, LENGTH(capital)
  FROM table
 WHERE

Comment: Please name DBMS you are using and sharing sample input and output really help

Comment: Using Oracle RDBMS

Comment: Please add the Oracle tag to your question

Comment: sample Input 1st row: name: anand, city: chennai, country: india; 2nd row: sanju, city merut, country:india. Output will be the 2nd row

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, you can use `Length()`:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Length(Column1) = Length(Column2) and Length(Column1) = Length(Column3)
```

You can read more about `Length()` [on this page](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/length.php).

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood correctly

Please check below query

```
SELECT name, , city,  capital
FROM table WHERE
LENGTH(name) =  LENGTH(city)
and LENGTH(city) = LENGTH(capital);
```